Proving that a second order PDE is elliptic for |x|<1 and hyperbolic otherwise
Show that the following partial differential equation is elliptic inside the
unit ball B1 = { x | |x| < 1 } and is hyperbolic outside the unit ball.
$\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}(δ_{i,j} − x_ix_j)  *(∂^2u/∂_{xi} ∂_{xj})u=0 $
What I was thinking here that for i=j, I will have $δ_{i,j}=1$, and then I will have $ 1 - x_i$, and having the sum, I know that I should obtain $1-|x|^2>0$ which will lead to have it elliptic inside the ball (since all of the coefficients will be  positives) and hyperbolic outside the ball.
The thing that I am struggling to prove it formally and play with the sum. Any help?
